# Issue with GET http request in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http-headers, http-post

I'm having a serious issue with a GET request...

For some reason, when I set an NSString that is an authorization token that needs to be passed to the a header of an HTTP request, the authorization string is clearly not passed. Now this authorization token is created everytime I make a specific request to the web server to get a token back to make more requests to the web server.

So through some debugging, I took one of the authorization tokens and initialized an NSString to the token I recieved back, making the string static to that one token. Then when I make a post request with that SPECIFIC token, all is good..

But when I use the NSString that is initialized by the request I make, the header doesn't accept the NSSString..

Sorry for my wording... but here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", setAuthenticaionKey);
NSString *authKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"ClientLogin auth=%@", setAuthenticaionKey];
NSLog(@"%@", authKey);
setAuthenticaionKey = @"4Pm/WijuHdJP02PcVEWOEBk+aPfB0hH+APtKgtorR/xHE3VDDenLCXVEsbi3SeLFFQHbQ7v9vP4zoAzylM9ie0FOiJq41O8i3mV9Vta/f5+Nelgegb4OoQ==";
authKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"ClientLogin auth=%@", setAuthenticaionKey];
NSLog(@"%@", authKey);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://insight.fatspaniel.net/platform/rest/v1/user.json"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:authKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

So this works and I get back :

```
2013-07-15 16:29:47.221 PowerOneApp[7257:c07] {"user":{"userId":"settingj","firstName":"John","lastName":"Setting","email":"jsetting32@yahoo.com","siteListEid":1129945}}
```

But when I take out this line....

```
setAuthenticaionKey = @"4Pm/WijuHdJP02PcVEWOEBk+aPfB0hH+APtKgtorR/xHE3VDDenLCXVEsbi3SeLFFQHbQ7v9vP4zoAzylM9ie0FOiJq41O8i3mV9Vta/f5+Nelgegb4OoQ=="; // the static nsstring
```

I get this back :

```
2013-07-15 16:31:00.160 PowerOneApp[7282:c07] {"unexpectedException":{"reason":"E-AZNInject-azn.1-","message":"No Authorization header.  ","code":"REQUEST_INVALID"}}
```

Now I compare both the static token to the dynamic token that keeps getting reassigned to the `setAuthenticationKey` string variable and heres what they compare as:

```
2013-07-15 16:31:41.931 PowerOneApp[7300:c07] ClientLogin auth=jqsWR0RLoolfBNFwWAUM0W7NHSLs67i4h3xblbDDlfNHE3VDDenLCXVEsbi3SeLFFQHbQ7v9vP4zoAzylM9ie0FOiJq41O8ij8/zTwyBOpswf8czwtNuWg==
2013-07-15 16:31:41.931 PowerOneApp[7300:c07] ClientLogin auth=4Pm/WijuHdJP02PcVEWOEBk+aPfB0hH+APtKgtorR/xHE3VDDenLCXVEsbi3SeLFFQHbQ7v9vP4zoAzylM9ie0FOiJq41O8i3mV9Vta/f5+Nelgegb4OoQ==
```

Notice there both the same length and ending with the same '=='. I also use WireShark to check if the headers are being posted correctly, but when I use the static token, everything gets posted, when I don't use the static token, nothing is posted to that field for the authorization token HTTPheaderfield. Also I log the token string BEFORE any headers are set and I actually get a full token string back, so it's just not posting for some odd reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved...

Apparently, when I checked the count of both individual strings, the dynamically allocated token was returning a count of 121 whereas the static token was return 120....

So I used this to resolve the issue:

```
NSString *anotherNewString = [newStr substringToIndex:[newStr length] - 1];
```

So now, the string returns 120 characters and the http request now recognizes the string as an actual header type....